# Who gets treated better in the afterlife?

Tags: heaven, christian-living, afterlife

What sort of people get treated better in the afterlife ?

And how much do the little things weigh(like praying every evening, or occasionally swearing) in comparison to the bigger ones ?

Even if it sounds like a rather idiotic question, would be nice to get serious answers. Thanks for you answers in advance

Comment: This appears to be a philosophical question, not specifically about Christianity.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! We require questions here to be more tightly focused, and to usually address a single denomination. But if you asked me personally, I'd say that [1 Corinthians 3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%203&version=NIV) tells us that all our life's work will be put through the furnace, and the only things that will remain are what we did to build the Kingdom of God.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  To add to what @curiousdannii said, (this is my personal opinion, probably NOT supported in the Bible) it's more in proportion to our love for God.  Just like the more we appreciate our spouse the happier we are.  So if we do those things out of our love for God or gratitude to God (in contrast to scoring heavenly points) we will have better rewards in heaven, I think.

Comment: Matthew 5:19 "Whoever, therefore, shall break one of these
least commandments, and teach others to do so,
shall be called least in the Kingdom of
Heaven; but whoever shall do and teach them
shall be called great in the Kingdom of Heaven."

Comment: Curiously, the little things are usually what define our commitment to the big things. Jesus expects us to become perfect (Matt 5:48), a process that can take a lifetime that requires commitment (the more religious term used by some is "conviction"). Ask yourself, how committed are you?

Comment: I'll be happy enough if I avoid going to the smoking section.

Comment: Honestly, I think that this is an answerable question. There are multiple Bible verses that talk about this topic.